# Valgrind / Memory Errors

Tags: c, list, memory, linked-list, valgrind

I'm receiving the following errors repeatedly throughout my code when I use valgrind.  I'm not quite sure what these mean and I can't identify the uninitialized values.

```
==16795== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==16795==    at 0x4A06E8A: strcmp (mc_replace_strmem.c:412)
==16795==    by 0x4009C7: dictionary_add (libdictionary.c:44)
==16795==    by 0x40061B: main (part2.c:28)
==16795== 
==16795== Invalid write of size 1
==16795==    at 0x4A082E7: strcpy (mc_replace_strmem.c:303)
==16795==    by 0x400AA8: dictionary_add (libdictionary.c:57)
==16795==    by 0x40061B: main (part2.c:28)
==16795==  Address 0x4c361a3 is 0 bytes after a block of size 3 alloc'd
==16795==    at 0x4A05E1C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==16795==    by 0x400931: node_newnode (libdictionary.c:28)
==16795==    by 0x400A8C: dictionary_add (libdictionary.c:54)
==16795==    by 0x40061B: main (part2.c:28)
```

I'm creating a linked-list data structure and these are the functions being called when this memory error is given.

// Here are the constructions of both a node and the dictionary data struct.

```
typedef struct node
{
char* key;
char* value;
struct node* next;
}node;


typedef struct _dictionary_t
{
node* head;

} dictionary_t;
```

// First a new dictionary is created

```
void dictionary_init(dictionary_t *d)
{
d->head = NULL;
d->head = malloc(sizeof(node));
node_init(d->head);
}
```

// A new node is created using the node_init method.

```
void node_init(node *n)
{
n->key = NULL;
n->value =NULL;

n->key = malloc(sizeof(char));
n->value = malloc(sizeof(char));
n->next = NULL;
}
```

// This new node method is used after the original initialization (when we are adding new terms)  The previous one is specifically for creating a sentinel at the beginning of the structure upon creation.

```
void node_newnode(node *n, int x, int y)
{
n->key = NULL;
n->value = NULL;

n->key = malloc(x*sizeof(char));
n->value = malloc(y*sizeof(char));
n->next = NULL;
}
```

// This function is also being called to add "key" and "value" as a pair in this case.

```
int dictionary_add(dictionary_t *d, const char *key, const char *value)
{
node *current;
current =  d->head;
if(strcmp(current->key,key)==0)
        return -1;
while(current->next != NULL){
        current=current->next;
        if(strcmp(current->key,key)==0)
                return -1;
}
        current->next = NULL;
        current->next = malloc(sizeof(node));

        node_newnode(current->next,strlen(key),strlen(value));

        current = current->next;
        strcpy((current->key), key);
        strcpy((current->value),value);
        return 0;
}
```

Anyone have any ideas on why I'm getting those errors.  The main method has thus far only created a dictionary and called the add function.  Valgrind is reporting 45+ errors over 38 contexts over the course of 8 function calls.  I think these are probably small errors that I'm committing repeatedly.

I'm now also getting the same errors with this function.  A valgrind --track-origins=yes command traces it to a stack allocation in the following function:

```
int dictionary_parse(dictionary_t *d, char *key_value)
{
char* colon;
char* space;
colon = key_value;
space = key_value;

space++;

int key_length = -1; //Default key length to check for failure

int i=0;
int j=0;   // Loop variables
int k=0;

int length = strlen(key_value);

for(i=0;i<length-2;i++){
        if(*colon == ':' && *space == ' '){
                key_length = i;
                break;
        }
        colon++;
        space++;
}

if(key_length == -1 || key_length == 0)
        return -1;

int value_length = length-2-key_length;

colon = key_value;


char key_word[key_length];
key_word[0] = '\0';
char value_word[value_length];
value_word[0] = '\0';

for(j=0;j<key_length;j++){
key_word[j] = *colon;
colon++;
}

space++;

for(k=0; k<value_length;k++){
value_word[k] = *space;
space++;
}


char* finalkey[key_length];
strcpy((char*)finalkey,key_word);
char* finalvalue[value_length];
strcpy((char*)finalvalue,value_word);

dictionary_add(d,(char*)finalkey,(char*)finalvalue);    

return 0;

}
```

Thanks,
-newprogrammer

Comment: by the way, why do you assign `NULL` to your variables immediately before assigning the a pointer returned by `malloc` ? That's not necessary.

Answer (score 10):

The first error ("Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)") is because the character pointed to by `current->key` was never initialised.  You allocated a byte for it in `node_init()`, but you never actually set that byte to anything.  If you want the `head` node's `key` to act like an empty string, change `node_init()` like this:

```
n->key = malloc(sizeof(char));
n->key[0] = '\0';
```

The second error ("Invalid write of size 1") is because your `node_newnode()` function is allocating one byte less than is needed for the strings.  `strlen(key)` counts the actual characters in the string, but one more byte is needed for the null terminator character.  Use:

```
node_newnode(current->next,strlen(key) + 1,strlen(value) + 1);
```

(but personally I would just pass `key` and `value` to `node_newnode()`, and have it do both the allocation and the `strcpy()`).